# PHP Linear clearing of a text file that is not equal to the given value

Tags: php, file, line, equals

Thanks to the friends who added the comment (Prashant Pokhriyal, Steve, Ulrich Eckhardt). I do not know in the previous question why the lines that I wrote separately were in a line? I will edit the previous question.

Content of the text file (test.txt):

```
115.5.108.249 2015-03-01
118.110.6.87 2018-01-03
36.120.105.13 2018-04-06
```

I'm familiar with the following:

```
<?php 
    $fname = "test.txt";
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    foreach($lines as $line) if(!strstr($line, $date)) $out .= $line;  
    $f = fopen($fname, "w");  
    fwrite($f, $out);  
    fclose($f);
?>
```

This command will only delete the line that contains the current server history and date ($date). I want this command to run in reverse. Line cleaner whose history (date) is old and no match with current server date (The server where PHP runs). I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Please specify what is each field. I see there are three dates for three servers. So with which of the date you want to compare to delete that line?

Comment: Is that sample one line? Because it looks to have three dates in it, which complicates what you're asking.

Comment: Since this looks like homework, people will hesitate to help you. You also don't show any effort, don't even ask a specific question concerning a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the friends who added the comment (Prashant Pokhriyal, Steve, Ulrich Eckhardt).
I do not know in the previous question why the lines that I wrote separately were in a line? I will edit the previous question.

Content of the text file (test.txt):

```
115.5.108.249 2015-03-01
118.110.6.87 2018-01-03
36.120.105.13 2018-04-06
```

I'm familiar with the following:

```
 <?php 
    $fname = "test.txt";
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    foreach($lines as $line) if(!strstr($line, $date)) $out .= $line;  
    $f = fopen($fname, "w");  
    fwrite($f, $out);  
    fclose($f);
?>
```

This command will only delete the line that contains the current server history and date ($date). I want this command to run in reverse. Line cleaner whose history (date) is old and no match with current server date (The server where PHP runs).
I hope you understand what I mean.